# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'search')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I am completely new to this. Tried for hours to find some sort of explanation on this.
Basically I am trying to replicate a project to understand the main concepts. In the project the code apparently works just fine, I however receive a "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'search')" error. I hope that someone here can explain to me, what I am missing.

I believe the Errors to come from the following lines of code:

SigninScreen:

```
 const redirect = props.location.search
 ? props.location.search.split("=")[1]
 : "/";
```

ProductScreen:

```
const productId = props.match.params.id;
```

Kind Regards,

Makani

SigninScreen:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link, } from "react-router-dom";
import { signin } from "../actions/userActions";
import Loadingbox from "../components/LoadingBox";
import MessageBox from "../components/MessageBox";

export default function SigninScreen(props) {

const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const redirect = props.location.search
 ? props.location.search.split("=")[1]
 : "/";

const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
const { userInfo, loading, error } = userSignin;
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  dispatch(signin(email, password));
  };
useEffect(() => {
  if (userInfo) {
    props.history.push(redirect);
  }
}, [props.history, redirect, userInfo]);

return ( ...  );
}
```

ProductScreen:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { detailsProduct } from "../actions/productActions";
import LoadingBox from "../components/LoadingBox";
import MessageBox from "../components/MessageBox";
import Rating from "../components/Rating";

export default function ProductScreen(props) {

const productId = props.match.params.id;
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);
const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(detailsProduct(productId));
}, [dispatch, productId]);

const addToCartHandler = () => {
  props.history.push(`/cart/${productId}?qty=${qty}`);
};

return ( ...  );
}
```

Comment: Use `props?.location?.search` instead of `props.location.search` and check if your `props.location` have correct structure as  https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/location

Comment: Hi @VitaliyRayets
Thank you so much, this worked, at least for the SigninScreen. 
Could you have a look at the code for the  CartScreen and ProductScreen? I will post the code below.

Thank you so much in advance.

Kind Regards

Makani

CartScreen:

export default function Cartscreen(props) {
  const productId = props.match.params.id;

  const qty = props.location.search
    ? Number(props.location.search.split("=")[1])
    : 1;

Comment: You problem not in `CartScreen` or `ProductScreen`, @Agney right, you must find mistake in your `router.js`. Share how you set components to `Route`

Comment: <main>
   <Routes>
      <Route path="/cart/:id?" component={CartScreen} element={<CartScreen/>}> 
          </Route>
      <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen} element= 
          {<ProductScreen/>}></Route>
      <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} element={<HomeScreen/>} exact> 
          </Route>
      <Route path="/signin" component={SigninScreen} element={<SigninScreen/>}> 
         </Route>
      <Route path="/register" component={RegisterScreen} element= 
         {<RegisterScreen/>}></Route>
   </Routes> </main>

Comment: Yup, you have mistake, use `Switch` instead of `Routes`

Comment: Hi @VitaliyRayets
I tried that before, but then I get this error : Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.

Comment: Hi @VitaliyRayets, 
I believe there was an update, and now "Switch" is replaced by "Routes", and "component" is placed by "element", but I cannot get it to work

Comment: You use v6 react-router and you must use `useSearchParams` instead of props or `useLocation`

Comment: Thanks for the hint
I am now using useNavigate instead of props.history and useLocation instead of props.location. However I am still struggling with useSearchParams:
This is my ProductScreen:
 import { Link, useSearchParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
 const params = useSearchParams; const productId = params.match.id;
This is the Route:
   <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen} element {<ProductScreen 
       />}></Route>
And this is the URL:
http://localhost:3000/product/1
I am still getting this error
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"

Comment: Just read https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

Comment: `const { id } = useParams();` instead of `const params = useSearchParams; const productId = params.match.id`

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#reading-url-params

Comment: @VitaliyRayets - perfect thank you

Answer (score 3):

I had same error.
In v6 you have to use `useLocaion()` like:

```
const location = useLocation();
const redirect = location.search
    ? location.search.split('=')[1]
    : '/';
```

Comment: Solved for me while doing the udemy react class

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for React Router v5](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/location):

```
The router will provide you with a location object in a few places:
· Route component as this.props.location
· Route render as ({ location }) => ()
· Route children as ({ location }) => ()
· withRouter as this.props.location
```

A component receives the `location` prop automatically in 4 usages mentioned about. Since you have not described `withRouter`, I can only assume that your case is Option 1.

React Router adds the `location` prop to the component automatically if it is directly in the Route component.

```
// if this is the case, SignIn receives a location prop
<Route path="/path" component={SigninScreen} />
```

If you want to add `location` prop manually, you can use [`withRouter`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) higher order component.

```
export default withRouter(SignInScreen);
```